# I wrote a prolog code for my family tree. What's the problem with this code?

Tags: prolog

```
/*facts*/
female(Sufia).
female(Bilkis).
female(Nasima).
female(Rabeya).
female(NWife).
female(Eva).
female(Rekha).
female(Shammi).
female(Shanta).
female(TWife).
female(NSWife).
female(Jui).
female(SHWife).
female(TSWife).

male(Anowar).
male(Shahidul).
male(Khazal).
male(Shafik).
male(Nahid).
male(Jahorul).
male(Naim).
male(Tanim).
male(Raiyan).
male(NSon).
male(JHusband).
male(Jubayer).
male(Shoddo).
male(TSon).
male(NSSon).
male(JSon).
male(SHSon).
male(TSSon).

parent(Anowar,Shahidul).
parent(Anowar,Nasima).
parent(Anowar,Shafik).
parent(Shahidul,Nahid).
parent(Shahidul,Eva).
parent(Nasima,Rekha).
parent(Nasima,Shammi).
parent(Nasima,Shanta).
parent(Shafik,Tanim).
parent(Shafik,Raiyan).
parent(Nahid,NSon).
parent(Rekha,Jui).
parent(Rekha,Jubayer).
parent(Shammi,Shoddo).
parent(Tanim,TSon).
parent(NSon,NSSon).
parent(Jui,JSon).
parent(Shoddo,SHSon).
parent(TSon,TSSon).

/*rules*/
mother(X,Y):-parent(X,Y),female(X).
father(X,Y):-parent(X,Y),male(X).
son(X,Y):-parent(X,Y),male(X).
daughter(X,Y) :- female(X),parent(X,Y).
sister(X,Y) :- female(Y),parent(Par,X),parent(Par,Y), X \= Y.

child(X, Y) :-parent(Y, X).
sibling(X,Y):-parent(Z,X),parent(Z,Y),X\=Y.
grandparent(X,Z):-parent(X,Y),parent(Y,Z).

firstCousin(X,Y):-grandparent(Z,X),grandparent(Z,Y),X\=Y.
secondCousin(X,Y):-grandparent(A,X),grandparent(B,Y),sibling(A,B),A\=B.

firstcousinOnceRemoved(X,Y):-child(X,Z),cousin(Z,Y).
firstcousinTwiceRemoved(X,Y):-grandparent(X,Z),cousin(Z,Y).
```

Comment: Please add some text to explain what's going wrong?

Comment: Please read the warnings produced by your Prolog system.

Answer (score 3):

You need to quote every name, otherwise these symbols are variables, not atoms.

Otherwise, just lowercase the first letter. To illustrate this last option, using [my pet project](https://github.com/CapelliC/prolog-snippets/tree/master/genealogy), here is the graph:

[image]

as obtained from this source

```erlang
:- module(answer_so, [answer_so/0]).
:- use_module(genealogy).

answer_so :- genealogy(answer_so, 'Answer SO').

parent_child(P,C) :- parent(P,C).

female(sufia).
female(bilkis).
female(nasima).
female(rabeya).
female(nwife).
female(eva).
female(rekha).
female(shammi).
female(shanta).
female(twife).
female(nswife).
female(jui).
female(shwife).
female(tswife).

male(anowar).
male(shahidul).
male(khazal).
male(shafik).
male(nahid).
male(jahorul).
male(naim).
male(tanim).
male(raiyan).
male(nson).
male(jhusband).
male(jubayer).
male(shoddo).
male(tson).
male(nsson).
male(json).
male(shson).
male(tsson).

parent(anowar,shahidul).
parent(anowar,nasima).
parent(anowar,shafik).
parent(shahidul,nahid).
parent(shahidul,eva).
parent(nasima,rekha).
parent(nasima,shammi).
parent(nasima,shanta).
parent(shafik,tanim).
parent(shafik,raiyan).
parent(nahid,nson).
parent(rekha,jui).
parent(rekha,jubayer).
parent(shammi,shoddo).
parent(tanim,tson).
parent(nson,nsson).
parent(jui,json).
parent(shoddo,shson).
parent(tson,tsson).
```

Seems there are no marriages...

Comment: Females are red, males are blue? Prior to the 20th, it used to be the other way around, red = Mars, etc

Comment: @false: Colors are of course easily changeable, not so much the set of attributes the graph must visualize. Apart gender, the family status (not apparent from OP' data) is clearly represented, as well as liveness...